# Memory warning when trying to load images in Collection View on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-leaks, uiimage, uicollectionview

I get this warning, when loading images in Collection View on iOS7

warning: `failed to set breakpoint site at 0x11428984c for breakpoint 1.1: Unable to read memory at breakpoint address.`

And this is how I load the images

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cellDesign* newCell = [collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *str = [combinedArrays[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
newCell.templateName.text = str
newCell.displayTemplate.image = [UIImage imageNamed:str];
return newCell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a memory warning, your code works fine and won't crash because of a memory insufficiency.
This warning is most probably caused by some internal Xcode IDE code, that tries to set a dynamic breakpoint using LLDB at some point in memory address "0x11428984c", but fails, because it is unable to read it.

Comment: Have a look at the Breakpoints navigator... and remove unwanted breakpoints, It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all my breakpoints and ran again. Worked After that.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because I was hitting a `preconditionFailure`